# Apache Django Mod_Wsgi - reload application automatically

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

My mod_wsgi is running in daemon mode but it won't reload my django app whenever I make changes to files.

Each time I have to reload apache's configuration.

I tried to us [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode), but it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, only the WSGI script file is checked for changes.

If the rest of your code lies outside of the WSGI file then it won't be automagically reloaded.

The [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Application_Reloading) has two suggestions. Either issue a SIGINT (`kill -2`) to the daemon or `touch` your WSGI file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you properly implement the code monitor as described in the following part of that document:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes